# Can't successfully run the command npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-angular@latest on ionic 3.2.0

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, npm, ionic3

I'm trying to set up a project using

- ionic version 3.2.0
- Cordova CLI: 8.0.0
- Node 12.13.1 (lts)
- Using Windows 10 (If it helps)

When I try to run the command `ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0` the terminal prompts me `? Looks like this is an angular project, would you like to install @ionic/cli-p lugin-angular and continue? (Y/n)` and then when I press y and ENTER key the error message comes out.

[image]

Tried to run this command `npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-angular@latest` individually but the same error shows. Looked for and tried a lot of solutions but it doesn't work. This is getting very frustrating. Can Any of you guys help me?

Some solutions that I tried previously which had not effect on the error. It keeps on coming.

1. `npm install -g @angular/angular-cli` (Still prompts me to run `? Looks like this is an angular project, would you like to install @ionic/cli-p lugin-angular and continue? (Y/n)` Then comes the Error)
2. `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` (No change on the Error message)
3. `npm install @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova npm uninstall -g ionic npm install -g ionic@3.2.0`
   (Same Error Pops up)

*New to Ionic & Cordova. Can Anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try deleting your node modules then run npm install...worked for me an ionic 3 project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess a complete re-installation got the issue fixed.